# Creating Programs that Interact with Yahoo Groups

Tags: mobile, yahoo-api

I have a Yahoo! Group that has its own Database tables for various reasons.  I'd like to create a mobile application (or web app) that performs CRUD operations on such tables.  Does anyone have any clue as to how I can get started on learning how to do this (if at all?)

Comment: Although this is not an answer I have been looking to do the same and came across an API mentioned in this link. <http://www.archiveteam.org/index.php?title=Yahoo!_Groups> Might be of assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Yahoo! Groups does not have an external API. But, you might be able to use Export Table functionality which delivers the database records in CSV format.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I guess the CSV exports will have to do, cheers.